# Assign Array to property of a view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, uitableview

I've got a `TableViewController` where I want to display some data from `AppDelegate.m`

To do this I put some code in `AppDelegate` to Assign my Array to the property of the `viewController`, but I've got some problem with the syntax to do this.

My storyboard map is like that :

- The storyboard’s initial view controller is a `Tab Bar Controller`
- The `CalculateViewController` sits inside a navigation controller in the first tab
- The `AircraftSelectViewController` sits inside the first cell of my `CalculateViewController`

So I've got this part of code :

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UINavigationController *navigationController = [tabBarControllerNew viewControllers][0];
```

But I don't know how to explain to `AppDelegate` that my `AircraftSelectViewController` (`UITableViewController`) sits inside another `UITableViewController` (`CalculateViewController`).

Anyone knows how to do this ?
thx

EDIT :

I would like to do something like this, but i don't find the right syntax :

```
UITabBarController *tabBarControllerNew = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *navigationControllerNew = [tabBarControllerNew viewControllers][0];
    CalculateViewController *calculateViewController = [navigationControllerNew viewControllers][0];
    AircraftSelectViewController *aircraftSelectViewController = [calculateViewController tableView][0];
    aircraftSelectViewController.aircraft = _aircraft;
```

Comment: You can pass your array to CalculatorViewController then you can assign that array to AircraftSelectViewController in cellForRowAtIndexPath. If you use custom tableview cell should have the reference to that array.

Comment: can you show the code how you are assigning array to AircraftSelectViewController?

Comment: Get the values of arrays in the CalculateViewController and then forward that values to AircraftSelectViewController and use the array there in AircraftSelectViewController.

Comment: @semlh : simply learn how to transfer the data from one viewcontroller to another in iOS , Google Can help you very well for this. Best Luck.

Comment: Refer This Stack-overflow Question's answers your problem will be solved. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers/20048208#20048208

Comment: I add this to my CalculateViewController.m :

    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pickAircraft"]) {
            AircraftSelectViewController *aircraftSelectViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
            aircraftSelectViewController.aircraft = _aircraft;
        }
    }

And it works fine.

Thx for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `CalculateViewController.h`

create a array property with the name aircraft.

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSArray *aircraft;
```

in `AppDelegate.m`

```
 CalculateViewController *calculateViewController = [navigationControllerNew viewControllers][0];
    calculateViewController.aircraft = _aircraft //or array which you have created in app delegate.
```

in `CalculateViewController.m`

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method

assign the cell your array value.

```
cell.textLabel.text = [self.aircraft objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. I've already do it and it works fine. But i would like to assign my Array in the AircraftSelectViewController. I will try to transfer data between the two ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define a variable in AppDelegate

```
@property(nonatomic, strong)    NSMutableArray *galleryImages;
```

and In your viewController, you can `get and set` the value Of this arrays like

```
#import "Appdelegate.h"
```

init your appDelegate object and

```
appDelegate.galleryImages = // assign here;
```

Comment: In this case i've got my Data in Appdelegate.m and i just want to tell it that my AircraftSelectViewController is in CalculateViewController, in order to assign the array like that : aircraftSelectViewController.aircraft = _aircraft;

Comment: I am not sure what do you want ?

Comment: I wanted to transfer data from one view controller to another. I did it with :  (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender { if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pickAircraft"]) { AircraftSelectViewController *aircraftSelectViewController = segue.destinationViewController; aircraftSelectViewController.aircraft = _aircraft; 

Thx for helping !

Comment: it should work so did you check the value of array before assigning that its not null

Comment: Indeed, it works. I was not very clear in my comment ;)